# Count results for the current date using fields of type datetime

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the entries for the current day and sum the total. Currently, I have a query that counts the entries per day. I am using the `datetime` field to achieve my end goal. What would be the best approach to count the entries for the current day and sum the total?

```
CREATE TABLE product_entry
    (`id` int, `entry_time` datetime, `product` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO product_entry
    (`id`, `entry_time`, `product`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-09-03 15:16:52', 'dud1'),
    (2, '2015-09-03 15:25:00', 'dud2'),
    (3, '2015-09-04 16:00:12', 'dud3'),
    (4, '2015-09-04 17:23:29', 'dud4')
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91681/1)

Query

```
SELECT entry_time, count(*)
FROM product_entry
GROUP BY hour( entry_time ) , day( entry_time )
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE product_entry
    (`id` int, `entry_time` datetime, `product` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO product_entry
    (`id`, `entry_time`, `product`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-09-03 15:16:52', 'dud1'),
    (2, '2015-09-03 15:25:00', 'dud2'),
    (3, '2015-09-04 16:00:12', 'dud3'),
    (4, '2015-09-04 17:23:29', 'dud4')
;
```

Comment: What's the 'present day'? And what should the result set look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of your question says *Count results for the **current date** ...*, but the query you have tried suggests you want to show result counts for every distinct date. I am not sure which one you need. If the former is the case, you could simply use:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `product_entry` WHERE DATE(`entry_time`) =  CURDATE()
```

Comment: You are correct, this is exactly what I was looking for. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

To get count for today:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `product_entry` WHERE DATE(`entry_time`) =  CURRENT_DATE
```

To get count for yesterday (needed when You want to get entries at end of the day):

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `product_entry` WHERE DATE(`entry_time`) =  SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
```

For all time grouped by date and formated:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(entry_time,'%Y-%m-%d'), count(*)
FROM product_entry
GROUP BY date(entry_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is MSSQL Code maybe your help

```html
SELECT day([product_entry].[entry_time])as input, count(*) as Miktar
FROM [product_entry]
GROUP BY day([entry_time])
```